# Error when deploying with Google Cloud Service & asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform

I was following a demo step from Google to deploy a simple Hello world in asp.net using Visual Studio Code (tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world). When I get to the step "Deploy the application to your Windows instance" I get the following error : 

`Time Elapsed 00:00:05.72
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Users\PhilippeTrudel\AppData\Local\Temp\wjb0vfk2.mhs" -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site",publishSettings="C:\Users\PhilippeTrudel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpABC8.tmp" -allowUntrusted
Info: Using ID 'f848fc7f-44cb-4243-9743-ef34b9cc3877' for connections to the remote server.
Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("35.225.64.241"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 35.225.64.241:8172
Error count: 1.
Failed to publish project 1-hello-world.`

I really don't know what to do, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server seems to open on port 80 and the port 8172 is not open. Timeout generally means that a firewall is probably blocking access to the server.

You can try out the following:

Make sure the server installed with the same.net framework as your visual studio

- (e.g ASP, ASP.net 4.5…)
- Make sure port 8172 is open on the server(8172 is used for web
  deploy)
- The firewall on your computer is not blocking the request to the server

Comment: worked for the firewall haha thanks !

Comment: Awesome! Good that it works now